# Docker-compose behaves differently on MAC and Windows PC

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using the following **docker-compose.yaml**, which successfully builds on **MAC** but, it fails on **Win PC**:

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/atlas
    privileged: true
    command: |
      /bin/bash -c "atlas deployments setup --type local --port 27778 --bindIpAll --username root --password root --force && tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 27778:27778
```

I have Docker Desktop on both laptops. I am using Iterm2 and Win PowerShell on the other.
I tried to modify the command for Windows, but still get an error..

```
command: sh -c "atlas deployments setup --type local --port 27778 --bindIpAll --username root --password root --force && tail -f /dev/null"
```

The error on Win PC:

```
3/3: Creating your deployment local844... 
mongo-1  | Error: exit status 127:
```

It is strange that the exact same .yaml runs smoothly on a MAC.. any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What is this command supposed to connect to?  It looks like you do some setup step, and then the main container command winds up being a no-op `tail -f /dev/null`; can you delete this long-running no-op container, and put the setup command somewhere else (maybe another container's entrypoint wrapper script)?

Comment: `/var/run/docker.sock` is a Linux path to the Docker daemon's socket. Depending on your Windows setup it might work and it might not.

Comment: I changed the path, but I keep getting the same error.. now checking your suggestion @DavidMaze